# What is the significance of Jesus being a carpenter?

Tags: jesus, creation, layers-of-meaning

Is there any significance in the fact that Jesus was a carpenter?  Note the references in Matt 13:55, Mark 6:3 to Jesus being a carpenter and son of a carpenter.

My thoughts are that the profession can be seen to mirror the creation of the universe by God, considering that carpentry involves creating complex things as well.

Comment: Hi, Aleksandr! - Please state which [Book - Chapter : Verse(s) ] you are referring to. - Maybe update your question by citing Mark 6:3, if it supports your question.

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your question.  Please remember to take the tour (link below) to better understand how this site works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Was Jesus a Carpenter by profession?** - In Mark 6:3, the trade of carpentry does appear to be associated with Jesus (Yeshua, ישׁוּעָ) of Nazareth.

**Mark 6:3 [KJV]**
"Is not this **the carpenter**, the son of Mary, the brother of James, and Joses, and of Juda, and Simon? and are not his sisters here with us? And they were offended at him."

**Mark 6:3 [ESV]**
"Is not this **the carpenter**, the son of Mary and brother of James and Joses and Judas and Simon? And are not his sisters here with us?” And they took offense at him.

**Mark 6:3 [NASB]**
"Is not this **the carpenter**, the son of Mary, and brother of James and Joses and Judas and Simon? Are not His sisters here with us?” And they took offense at Him."

**Mark 6:3 [NIV]**
"Isn’t this **the carpenter**? Isn’t this Mary’s son and the brother of James, Joseph, Judas and Simon? Aren’t his sisters here with us?” And they took offense at him."

**Was Elohim / God ever referred to as a Carpenter?**

- No.

Readers of Exodus 27:1, 25:10, 26:15 could associate the Acacia (Shittim, שִׁטִּ֑ים) wood (Atsey, עֲצֵ֣י ) materials requested for construction of the Ark, Tabernacle, Altar with carpentry - since cut wood appears to be acceptable practice for crafting holy instruments.

**What profession is Elohim / God associated with?**

- The Potter (Ha-Yotser, הַיֹּצֵ֖ר).
- Our Potter (Yotser-Nu, יֹצְרֵ֔נוּ ).

Isaiah 64:7 [MT]

> [7] "And now, YHVH, You are our Father; we are the clay, and You are **our-Potter**, and all of us are Your handiwork." (וְעַתָּ֥ה יְהֹוָ֖ה אָבִ֣ינוּ אָ֑תָּה אֲנַ֚חְנוּ הַחֹ֙מֶר֙ וְאַתָּ֣ה **יֹֽצְרֵ֔נוּ** וּמַֽעֲשֵׂ֥ה יָֽדְךָ֖ כֻּלָּֽנוּ)

Answer (score 1):

The operative word in both Matt 13:55 and Mark 6:3 is τέκτων (tekton) which BDAG suggests is:

> "**One who constructs, *builder, carpenter***"

The Cambridge Commentary offers this helpful background (on Mark 6:3):

> 3. Is not this the carpenter?] Save in this one place, our Lord is nowhere Himself called “the Carpenter.” According to the custom of the
>    Jews, even the Rabbis learnt some handicraft. One of their proverbs
>    was that “he who taught not his son a trade, taught him to be a
>    thief.” Hence St Paul learnt to “labour with his own hands” at the
>    trade of a tent-maker (Acts 18:3; 1 Thessalonians 2:9; 1 Corinthians
>    4:12). “In the cities the carpenters would be Greeks, and skilled
>    workmen; the carpenter of a provincial village could only have held a
>    very humble position, and secured a very moderate competence.”
>    Farrar’s Life of Christ, I. 81.

That Jesus' pre-ministry profession, and that of Joseph, was "humble" is beyond dispute and consistent with Jesus' lowly (earthly) origins, see Phil 2:5-8.  It this consistent humility of Jesus that makes His exultation to the "highest" so profound, as recorded in Phil 2:9-11 -

> Therefore God exalted Him to the highest place and gave Him the name
> above all names, that at the name of Jesus every knee should bow, in
> heaven and on earth and under the earth, and every tongue confess that
> Jesus Christ is Lord, to the glory of God the Father.

Comment: It's interesting how much artwork depicts Jesus not as a carpenter (building construction framing, requiring heavy labour), but as a cabinet-maker (crafting fine furniture), especially in a place and time where wooden furniture would have been considered a luxury item. That he mostly worked with clay and stone construction seems far more likely, but that would hurt the common image of a skinny effeminate looking Jesus. [The Feminization of Christ and the Church — Boston Catholic Journal](http://www.boston-catholic-journal.com/feminization-of-christ-and-the-church.htm).

Answer (score 0):

### Jesus was Not a Carpenter

This is the only instance of him called a Carpenter, and *son of Mary* without mention of the father. There is a very significant variant that says "son of the Carpenter and Mary". It is likely that the later scribes tried to remove the father, to push the virgin birth narrative of Matthew-Luke. I could only find references of this variant in the [NRSV](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Mark%206:2-4&version=NRSVUE), NABRE and NET Bible, which suggest a deliberate attempt to cover up a strong variant among all Bible versions. [NET](https://www.stepbible.org/?q=version=ESV%7Cversion=NETfull%7Cversion=THGNT%7Cversion=DRC%7Cversion=VulgJ%7Creference=Mark.6.3&options=NGVUVH&display=INTERLEAVED) explains this variant by harmonization due to offence, which is very weak, there is nothing offensive about the Carpenter profession for Jesus, for the Christian scribes:

> Evidently because of the possible offensiveness of designating Jesus a carpenter, several mss ([Ƥ45vid] f13 33vid [565 579] 700 [2542] pc it vgmss) harmonize the words “carpenter, the son” to the parallel passage in Matt 13:55, “the son of the carpenter.” Almost all the rest of the mss read “the carpenter, the son.” Since the explicit designation of Jesus as a carpenter is the more difficult reading, and is much better attested, it is most likely correct.

Metzger textual commentary says "**All** uncials, many miniscules, and important early versions" has this variant, it is not just "some witnesses" as [NABRE](https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Mark%206:2-4&version=NABRE) states, but numerous and early, including the oldest p45, Old Latin and Vulgate, many other languages and Origen. Metzger also presupposes the argument of objection against the Carpenter status and does not even consider that it could be the actual original reading.

[Laparola](https://www.theword.net/bin/get.php/Variant+Readings+of+the+New+Testament.cmt.exe) apparatus:

- τοῦ τέκτονος υἱὸς καί] (see Matthew 13:55) (p45vid 13 l547m ὁ υἱὸς) (Σ* 565 579 2542 omit καί) f13 33vid 700 (1253 2148 omit τοῦ) (ℓ10 τοῦ τέκτων ὁ υἱὸς) ℓ31 ℓ48 ℓ184 ℓ299 ℓ387 ℓ547 ℓ890 ℓ1642 (346 ℓ1627 ite vgmss ὁ υἱὸς and omit καί) ita itaur itb itc iti itr1 vgmss copbo(mss) (eth) arm geo2 Origen